# RestSharp calling my WebApi parameter is blank

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, restsharp

- RestSharp 105.2.3
- WebAPI 2

So I have a simple WebApi controller as such:

```
public class EnettController : ApiController
{
    private readonly DebitService _EnettService;

    public EnettController()
    {
        _EnettService = new DebitService();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ProcessDirectDebitResponse ProcessDirectDebit([FromBody] ProcessDirectDebitRequest aRequest)
    {
    }
}
```

and from my test harness I call it with the following RestSharp code:

```
RestClient client = new RestClient($"http://{txtHost.Text}:{txtPort.Text}");

ProcessDirectDebitRequest dataForRequest = new ProcessDirectDebitRequest
                                           {
                                               AgentId = "James Bond",
                                               DepartureDate = DateTime.Now,
                                               Version = "123"
                                           };

RestRequest request = new RestRequest("api/Enett", Method.POST)
                      {
                          RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json
                      };
request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
request.AddBody(dataForRequest);

IRestResponse<ProcessDirectDebitResponse> response = client.Execute<ProcessDirectDebitResponse>(request);

if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
{
    MessageBox.Show($"Did not yet a 200 response. Got instead {response.StatusCode}");
}
```

My WebAPI end point is hit no problem but aRequest is always NULL. So I am missing something obvious here I just cannot see what it is. Why is aRequest always NULL?

Comment: Seems to be fine on first glance. Could inspect the request payload being sent using fiddler or similar tools? May be you could also try `request.AddJsonBody(dataForRequest);`

Comment: AddJsonBody() makes no difference. Still trying to get Fiddler to see the request.

Comment: That's right, shouldn't make any difference; just want to make sure there wasn't any typo while setting Content-Type. Should get some info if you look into the request payload and headers.

Comment: Looks like a RestSharp [issue](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/issues/622)

Comment: @SergeyShushlyapin How so? I am not calling AddParameter?

Comment: Ok, not this one, my bad.. I run your code on the same RestSharp version and WebApi2 project and it works fine (on my machine). So, I _guess_ the issue might be not in the code itself but in the environment.

Comment: @SergeyShushlyapin Thanks for that.... So aRequest is populated for you? I'll dumb down my ProcessDirectDebitRequest as it contains additional properties and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Yep. Tried with IIS Express and IIS 10 - works fine. And also experimented with .Net versions (from 4.5.2 till 4.6.2).

Comment: If you suspect your additional properties in the request object, then try passing anonymous object - `request.AddBody(new {
                                               AgentId = "James Bond",
                                               DepartureDate = DateTime.Now,
                                               Version = "123"
                                           });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here turned out to be that the ProcessDirectDebitRequest class had been decorated as [Serializable] resulting in the following payload being expected:

```
{
  "<AgentId>k__BackingField": "sample string 1",
  "<DepartureDate>k__BackingField": "2017-02-22T12:01:25.8332359+11:00",
  "<Version>k__BackingField": "sample string 3"
}
```

instead of what what was expected which was:

```
{
  "AgentId": "sample string 1",
  "DepartureDate": "2017-02-22T12:01:25.8332359+11:00",
  "Version": "sample string 3"
}
```

There are a few ways around this depending on your needs:

1. Don't decorate with [Serialize]
2. Use config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings();  //Remove backing fields and keep [Serialize]
3. Expressly use [DataContract], [DataMember]